# Where can I find ara-wsgi to install ARA for Ansible on Ubuntu with Apache+mod_wsgi?

Tags: ubuntu, apache2, ansible, wsgi

I'am trying to install ARA (https://github.com/openstack/ara) on an Ubuntu 16.04 to monitor my Ansible playbook executions

I follow carrefully the documentation (http://ara.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and when I configure Apache2 for ARA, the documentation asks to copy a WSGI script, ara-wsgi, to /var/www/ara/ (http://ara.readthedocs.io/en/latest/webserver.html#id2).

But I don't find anywhere this ara-wsgi file. It should be installed with ARA (when I made pip install ara) but I don't know where is it.

Could you help me please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into the same issue on Fedora 25 and on Centos 7. 
The solution that worked for me was to install ARA directly from their Git repo:

```
pip install git+https://git.openstack.org/openstack/ara
```

It is mentioned as a installation option here: https://ara.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#installing-ara-from-trunk-source

EDIT: 
On the 7th of March 2017 I did just 'pip install ara' and discovered that version 0.12.1 was out. In this version I had /usr/bin/ara-wsgi available.

Comment: Thank you. I will try that next monday. I'll keep you posted.